# What is the better way to deploy laravel application in live server?

Tags: laravel, deployment

I am confused about the deployment of the laravel project in the live server.

I searched for this and found many solutions.

There are many processes to deploy laravel projects in a live server.

- Someone suggesting to remove all files and folder from `public` folder
- someone saying to change `.htaccess` etc.

What is the perfect way to deploy laravel projects in the live server?

If, I have to remove `public` folder then, why laravel included it?

If I have to copy `.htaccess` to root directory and need to change it.

Then why it is not used laravel as default. Would someone explain it to me, please?

Comment: The perfect way is to not deploy it to shared hosting, buy a VPS and deploy with git

Comment: So, in VPS server, no need to remove `public` folder and not to do other things in `.htaccess`? Can I keep it is in as localhost?

Comment: Exactly! You don't need to change anything when deploying to a VPS

Comment: Oh, thanks. But VPS price is so high. :( So, for shared hosting I have to face these hassle.:(

Comment: A digital ocean droplet is just 5$, and yes... there will be more hastle with the storage and queues and compiling assets....etc (it will be a nightmare)

Comment: Thanks for your kind information